# Excel Userform IF AND statement

Tags: excel, vba, if-statement, userform

I am trying to make an IF/AND statement in a userform.

I want to add the same Last Name and different First Name to a dynamic list.

My code is catching this as a duplicate value. I am able to add a fully unique Frist and Last Name.

In my code I pull the first name from TextBox2/Num2 and the last name from TextBox3/Num3.

Ex:
Adding John Doe to the list that already has Jane Doe will catch as a duplicate for the Last Name.

Current State of my worksheet
[image]

```vb
Dim Num1 As Long
Dim Num2 As Long
Dim Num3 As Long

On Error Resume Next
Num1 = Application.WorksheetFunction.Match(Me.TextBox1.Value, ws.Range("A2:A500000"), 0)
Num2 = Application.WorksheetFunction.Match(Me.TextBox2.Value, ws.Range("B2:B500000"), 0)
Num3 = Application.WorksheetFunction.Match(Me.TextBox3.Value, ws.Range("C2:C500000"), 0)
On Error GoTo 0

If Num1 > 0 Then
    MsgBox "Error! Duplicate EID detected", , "Duplicate Detected"
    Exit Sub
End If

If Num2 > 0 And Num3 > 0 Then
    MsgBox "Error! Duplicate NAME detected", , "Duplicate Detected"
    Exit Sub
End If
```

Comment: You could use `WorksheetFunction.CountIfs` instead of `Match`.

Comment: Or you could write `If Num2 <> 0 And Num3 <> 0 Then`

Comment: @ScottHoltzman - but the problem is that num2 and num3 might not be the same... i.e. `John` is matched on one row and `Doe` is matched on another.

Comment: @BigBen - Good point. In that case `If Num2 > 0 And (Num2 = Num3) Then`

Comment: @BigBen This opens the possibility of adding a fully duplicate entry. Unless I input this incorrectly. I just replaced `.Match` with `.CountIfs`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `WorksheetFunction.CountIfs` instead of `Match` and check if the result is greater than 0. That will search for the *combination* of the first and last name on the same row.

```vb
Dim firstName As String
firstName = Me.TextBox2.Value

Dim lastName As String
lastName = Me.TextBox3.Value

If WorksheetFunction.CountIfs(ws.Range("B:B"), firstName, ws.Range("C:C"), lastName) > 0 Then
    MsgBox "Error! Duplicate NAME detected", , "Duplicate Detected"
    Exit Sub
End If
```